# Action of an algebraic group induce a representation of its Lie algebra

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group over a field $K$ of characterstic zero acting on a vector space $V$. Then does this action induce a representation :
$$\Gamma : Lie(G) \to gl(V)$$

If yes, how ? Please help me understand this. I would appreciate if the explanation is simple and from all prespectives like thinking of $Lie(G)$ as derivations on the coordinate ring or as the tangent space at identity of $G$.

Comment: What is the characteristic of $G$?

Comment: @TsemoAristide It is over a field of characterstic zero. I have edited that in the question too.

Comment: Take the differential of $\rho\colon G\rightarrow GL(V)$, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1639031/group-action-of-linear-algebraic-group-g-on-itself-induces-a-representaion-of).

Answer (score 0):

A linear Group is also a linear map. Clearly linear maps can be represented as matrices. For a representation in $gl(V)$ it is required that no Matrix has vanishing determinant. This ensures in the case that $K$ has characteristic Zero that the linear Group is invertible. And Groups must be invertible per definition.

Therefore this representation exists.